# Does the IR2110 provides isolation?

Tags: power-electronics, mosfet-driver

The datasheet for the IR2110 shows this diagram:

[image]

Where `vss` is the digital ground. Does this mean that the `block Vdd/Vcc LEVEL shift` provides some kind of electrical isolation? Or it's the digital side of the chip still connected  to the power side?

Comment: Page 1 of the datasheet cites the maximum differential between Vss and COM of +/-5V, so it's not really isolated. The normal use case for this IC is that Vss and COM are the same ground potential but are routed differently to keep the noisy switching isolated from the quiet control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything in the [datasheet](http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/ir2110.pdf) that indicates it provides isolation.

Normally for parts that offer isolation, the datasheet will include a rating for insulation voltage withstand, and also indicate safety agency approvals, such as UL or CSA.